# trouble importing csv file in matlab to perform pca

Tags: matlab, csv, dataset, pca

I have a problem , when i import a CSV dataset into Matlab , the separator doesn't work and Matlab showing me everything in one Column 
[this is a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxd37.jpg)

Comment: How are you loading the dataset?

Comment: using the import wizard

Answer (score 0):

use

```
data = dlmread('path/to/filename', ',');
```

if you want data as a table (which can be convenient) use

```
data = readtable(('path/to/filename', 'delimiter', ',', 'readvariablenames', true);
```

each of these assumes your data is properly formatted. that is, it is rectangular, columns are of a consistent type